# When linear regression is really a good model to be used?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

By definition of **linear regression model**:

If we note $Y$ the real random variable to be explained (endogenous variable, dependent or response) and $X$ the explanatory variable or fixed effect (exogenous). the linear regression model amounts to assuming that, on average, $E(Y)$, is an affine function of $X$.
$$E(Y) = f(X) = β_0 + β_1X$$
and we write $$Y = β_0 + β_1X + ε (*)$$
with $ε$ following the normal law $N(0,s)$.
Our main goal now is to find the parameters $$(β_0, β_1)$$ using the method of least squares.

My question comes from the remark that we use the observations of $Y$, $Y_i$ (which are random), to estimate the relationship that should model the expectation of $E(Y)$ as a linea function of $X$.

I explain this clearly with the following example:
Following the previous definition, I implemented the following code in Python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

W = np.random.normal(0,1.5,200)
X = np.array([i for i in range(200)])
Y = 0.5 + 0.001*X + W

X = X.reshape(-1,1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X, Y)

print('Slope  : {}'.format(regressor.coef_[0][0]))
print('Intercept : {}'.format(regressor.intercept_[0]))
```

I get the following results by running the script two times :

for the first time

```
Slope : -0.0014194386100520823
Intercept : 0.594949722904278
```

In second time

```
Slope : 0.00037356086526345897
Intercept : 0.6948322302347023
```

As you see, we obtain different values for the slope and the intercept between both tests and the in each case the values obtained are not close to the expected values 0.001 and 0.5 respectively, eventhough the response variable $Y$ is generated according to the theoritical relationship (*).

My question is two folds :

- When the results of the linear regression model are considered to be reliable ? unfortunately it was not the case in this situation where I judged that it will allow for the best modeling for the relationship between X and Y.
- Is there a different experimental setup when the results of the tests will match or would be close to the expected values ? In other words, how can I improve the previous results ? I see that by increasing the number of observations from 200 to 1000000 the results improve. However it seem to me not reasonable to expect that an experiment need to be repeated 1000000 times for us to be able to make good estimations for the parameters.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Plotting your data points and looking at them may help you understand what's happening. You are trying to estimate parameters to very high precision using data with high noise (here noise is high relative to the precision you want).  Increasing the number of data points helps as you've discovered.  Decreasing the noise, or increasing the parameter values will help (get lower *relative error*).  Try reading about confidence intervals in the context of linear regression.

Comment: As @bogovicj mentioned, I think the main reason is that in your example the noise in the data is quite big relative to the values of the data, therefore the regression model needs more observations to separate the signal from the noise.

Comment: Interpreting the coefficients alongside their standard error estimates could also be helpful.